# Determine possible combinations/permutations for 5 values which can be empty or not

Tags: permutations, combinations

This related to a computer programming rule I'm working on. I have 5 values:

t1
t2
t3
t4
t5

and each of these values can be empty or not. Whether each one is empty or not will change the result that is returned. I need to work out all the possible combinations/permutations (sorry not sure what is the correct term here) in this format:

// all empty
IsEmpty ( t1 ) and IsEmpty ( t2 ) and IsEmpty ( t3 ) and IsEmpty ( t4 ) and IsEmpty ( t5 )

// all empty except for t5
IsEmpty ( t1 ) and IsEmpty ( t2 ) and IsEmpty ( t3 ) and IsEmpty ( t4 ) and not IsEmpty ( t5 )

// all empty except for t4 and t5
IsEmpty ( t1 ) and IsEmpty ( t2 ) and IsEmpty ( t3 ) and not IsEmpty ( t4 ) and not IsEmpty ( t5 )

and so on. I'm hoping there's an easy way to list out all the possible combinations in the above format.

thanks,
Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have $2^5=32$ combinations.  You can get them all by counting from $0=0_2$ to$31=11111_2$ in binary, taking $1=full, 0=empty$

Comment: Thanks - do you know of any website that can generate the list of combinations for me by feeding in the required parameters?

Comment: Do you know place values in binary?  Use $16$ for $t1$, $8$ for $t2$, on down to $1$ for $t5$.  Add up the full ones.